# Get the Salesforce Id for the URL in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the controller, I specify the PageReference src as `http...../apex/mypage?id=' + {!a.Id}` and for href as "`!URLFOR("apex/mypage?id=" + a.Id)}` in the tag. But in jQuery:

```
$('#Link').click(function(){
    $("#iframe").attr("src", "/apex/mypage?id=" ??? );
}
```

To specify an URL in jQuery, how do I GET the Salesforce id in the URL. (Not the element Id but the 15 character "key" in SF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your javascript is in your Visualforce page you can simply use the same binding:

```
$('#Link').click(function(){
    $("#iframe").attr("src", "/apex/mypage?id={!a.Id}");
}
```

Assuming that `a` is available to the page (which it would appear to be so from the question).

If the code is not stored in the page directly, you could add a variable to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var accountId = "{!a.Id}";
</script>
```

And just use the variable `accountId` in the code you're bringing in from elsewhere (note the check to see if it's actually defined):

```
$('#Link').click(function(){
    var pageUrl = "/apex/mypage?id=" + (accountId ? accountId : "");
    $("#iframe").attr("src", pageUrl);
}
```

Another alternative would be to put the value into a hidden field somewhere:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!a.Id}" id="theId"/>
```

and then use jQuery to pull that input's value inside your click function.

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer @LaceySnr♦. But these ways are for the standard objects, if I'm right. What if I want to get the id of a wrapper class parameter (for example, if I've a COMMON_CITY parameter that contains the cities of Leads and Contacts). I was able to get the Ids only in the Pageblocktable. So how can I pull those Ids in JS?

Comment: You'd need to check the format of the parameter but I suspect it'd be a semicolon delimited list. In that case you should be able to assign the value to a javascript variable (2nd block of code in my answer) then use the javascript `.split` string method to get an array. Then you should be able to index into that, but if you're still stuck a new question might be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @LaceySnr♦. But I'm still stuck up and I've posted a new question in detail with the complete code.   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38430/displaying-the-textbody-commentbody-of-an-email-comment-in-a-popup